# What happens in Tornado if an error occurs during streaming?

Tags: python-3.x, tornado, chunked-encoding

I'm writing a streaming POST request handler in Tornado, using the [`@stream_request_body`](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.stream_request_body) class decorator and implementing the `data_received` method to handle chunked data. I have some resources that I want to ensure are closed when the request has been serviced.

If an error occurs within `data_received`, I can catch the exception, clean up resources and call `send_error`. But what happens if the connection is closed by the client? Does `post` get called in that case?

Comment: An unhandled exception in `data_received` results in a response with status code 599.

Comment: _connection is closed by the client_ in that case [RequestHandler.on_connection_close](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.on_connection_close) is called.

Comment: @Fian Cool! Do you know how I can force `AsyncHTTPClient` to close the connection abruptly? Is it enough to just stop yielding data from the `body_producer`? I'd like to add a test in my code for `on_connection_close`.

Comment: I don't have knowledge on that topic.