# Anything special required to use Tornado's data_received method without blocking?

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, tornado, nonblocking

I have a POST request handler that takes [streaming data as input](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.data_received) and writes it to AWS APIs. The data is sent to AWS using multiple inner requests, which are made via [`boto3`](https://github.com/boto/boto3). I believe `boto3` is blocking but [may release the GIL](http://ls.pwd.io/2013/06/parallel-s3-uploads-using-boto-and-threads-in-python/) when doing I/O: it seems to use [urllib3.connection](https://github.com/boto/botocore/blob/50ada9540428a39334a5b84a96ef375cbf06bfce/botocore/awsrequest.py#L22) internally. So I wrapped it in a call to [`run_in_executor`](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ioloop.html#tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.run_in_executor) - something like this cut-down code:

```
@stream_request_body
class Handler(RequestHandler):
    async def prepare(self):
        self.parser = BufferedParser()

    async def data_received(self, chunk):
        complete_part = self.parser.receive(chunk)
        if complete_part:
            await IOLoop.current().run_in_executor(
                None, self.send_via_boto, complete_part)

    async def post(self):
        self.set_header('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
        self.write("OK")
```

My question is: will the awaited call to `send_via_boto` block the client from uploading the next chunk? Do I need to implement something fancier, or should this already be non-blocking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"block the client from uploading the next chunk"* — a client uploads data not to your app directly, but to a TCP socket. That socket has a certain size, i.e. buffer, so if buffer is full, client will wait until it's emptied and then continue upload. Your app, with the help of Tornado, reads from this TCP-socket-buffer and empty it with the part that was read. The process of sending a chunk to AWS won't stop the client from uploading the data to TCP socket, even if you send data to AWS in a blocking way (i.e. without run_in_executor, but you will *block your server* from serving other requests). If you send data to AWS slower than client uploads, then your app would be bottleneck and will *prevent* (which is technically not the same as *blocking*) a client from uploading more.

Comment: Awesome, that's what I was hoping for. From looking at urllib3, it seems to use a plain socket underneath, so I think the output side will release the GIL and allow other requests to be served.

Comment: While you're here :) Maybe you have some insight into my other question? [What happens in Tornado if an error occurs during streaming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54226471/what-happens-in-tornado-if-an-error-occurs-during-streaming)